# R - find at which position values from one dataframe can be found in another one

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes with different lenghts.
Using the function below I have extracted every duplicate including originals and the duplicates appearing more than twice.

```
duplikat_n=matxt[(duplicated(matxt) | duplicated(matxt, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

Now I want to find at what Spot in the df matxt the duplicates are.

```
which(c(matxt==duplikat_n))
```

The following function gives me an error:

```
‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

So how can I check at which location in the dataframe matxt my duplicates are located ?

Example:

```
s <- data.frame(Y = sample(c("yes", "no","yes","test")))
x<- data.frame (Z= sample(c("test","random","hello")))
```

Neither

```
which(s%in%x)
```

works nor a version with

```
==
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output for that input.

Comment: Try use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: I have updated my post for a reproducable example

Comment: @Sebastian there's no duplicated values from `s` in `x` `data.frame`

Comment: I misspelled in my example, I've updated it again

Comment: Are the comparisons you want really just one column, or is that only for illustrative purposes?

Comment: They're really just one column.

Answer (score 0):

Comments to answer:

For your specific problem, you define `duplikat_n` as a subset of `matxt`. You can use the same definition to get the rows you put into the subset:

```
duplikat_n=matxt[(duplicated(matxt) | duplicated(matxt, fromLast = TRUE)), ]

# which rows did you use? these rows:
which(duplicated(matxt) | duplicated(matxt, fromLast = TRUE))
```

If, as you say, your data frames are just a single column, then you can just use the columns as vectors:

```
which(s[[1]] %in% x[[1]])
```